# Timeout error on deploying to Rinkeby from truffle migrate

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have just finished the CryptoZombies tutorials, and was trying to deploy the file following their instructions to the Rinkeby network. But I keep getting this timeout error and am lost on how to proceed.

```
$truffle migrate --network rinkeby

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:56
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
^
Error: There was a timeout while attempting to connect to the network.
       Check to see that your provider is valid.
       If you have a slow internet connection, try configuring a longer timeout in your Truffle config. Use the networks[networkName].networkCheckTimeout property to do this.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/index.js:56:1)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

My truffle-config.js is as follows:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

const mnemonic = "depth invite butter ...";

module.exports = {

  networks: {

    mainnet: {
      provider: function () {

        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_TOKEN")
      },
      network_id: "1"
    },

    rinkeby: {

      provider: function () {

        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/YOUR_TOKEN")
      },

      network_id: 4
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: And `YOUR_TOKEN` is your Infura project ID?

Comment: unfortunately not. had to leave some dumb thing! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep coolness of mind while learning the blockchain development complexities and connections.

In this case it was not clear from the tutorials I was following, but to actually deploy to any of the networks, you need to create a project id/token.

In this case as I was trying to deploy to the Rinkeby test network by Infura.io
--> I had to go to the website and create and account and then create a project, and the project key/id which I replaced in my truffle config and lo and behold! it works now.

Comment: Just wanted to +1 this. Sorted my issue out when using hotspot / internet cafes with TESTNET (which was driving me CRAZY)

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed this problem by setting *networkCheckTimeout* as *10000* before setting *provider* in truffle-config.js.

```
networks: {
  bsctest: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 10000, 
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/`),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 2000,
      skipDryRun: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you also can adjust timeout in HDWalletProvider configuration! this fixed an issue for me
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I searched for more than a week. Finally, I found the answer [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/softfair/p/Truffle-migirate-deploy-contract-ESOCKETTIMEDOUT.html), Not only change the `pollingInterval`, but also do this: in the module `web3-provider-engine`， modify the `timeout` a bigger number. Remember that, the module maybe imported more than one times, so change the value everywhere in your projects.

```
xhr({
    uri: targetUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newPayload),
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    timeout: 2000,  // change the value bigger
```